# How to render as pdf when loading the existing website into the VF page

Tags: visualforce, rerender

I have used the following cod to render as PDF, but website is not render when using the render as PDF/ but **if I remove the PDF, the webpage is loading.**

```
Code:

   <apex:page render="pdf">
// external webstie link (ex: bing.com)
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer the following.

[Check](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48226/how-to-view-the-website-in-vf-page-as-pdf/49033#49033)

We cant render as pdf. we can render only when using the third party tool.

Answer (score 4):

You can't put iFrames, Javascript and that sort of stuff in a PDF. The PDF render engine only looks at the DOM as it is when the page is loaded (HTML/CSS/VF).

You can get the content of the website (the source code) but there is no way to render that as a PDF in your visualforce page. Below is a code how to get the content if that helps:

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class MyClass
{
    public String content {get; set;}

    public void init()
    {
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://google.com');
        content = pageRef.getContent().toString();
    }
}
```

**Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="bbtest" action="{!init}" renderAs="PDF">
    <apex:outputText value="{!content}" />
</apex:page>
```

> You need to add the external website's domain name in `Remote Sites`.

You can probably use a headless browser and some fancy screen capture method, then add that as an image into your VF PDF, but that's a challenge that I'm leaving with you and good luck :)

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve here. But if you're about to load another website and generate PDF out of it, you won't be able to do that unfortunately.

Comment: You can't do that. You can get the source code of the page but you won't be able to render "as is" on your page. I've updated the answer of how to get the content of the page if that helps.

Comment: Because the PDF renderer does not support that. It only looks what is on the page at that given moment when the page loads. The PDF renderer is not capable to interpret Javascript or to load an iFrame etc. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_additional_render_pdf.htm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16268/discussion-between-lemon-and-bachovski).

Comment: You are give useless answer. pelasee provide the answer or else please allow some other person.

Comment: Dude anyone can post other answers too, it's not like I locked this answer. As you can see 5 people upvoted which means that they agree with what I answered, that what you are trying to achieve is simply not possible

Comment: See I just upvoted for encourage purpose. so I have upvoted and my friends up-voted... but you are product my new post question.

Comment: The question is still visible to every member in this community and anyone can provide additional answer at any time, so there is no need to post the same question multiple times.

Comment: I will wait please provide suitable answer for me. your answer not related for me

Comment: Ok. my question is how to render the page but your answer is render the content. so please change the answer and provide the solution if you know,.

Comment: Mate I don't know the solution and relax, if you don't like the answer you don't have to accept it. Stop being so annoying

Comment: Please let me know. if you know the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I just found one work around for this. We can use third party API to convert any URL into PDF.

Here is [site](http://pdfcrowd.com/html-to-pdf-api/#api-reference) that provide this service

Please note that this is paid service.

They also have Rest API that we can call from SFDC.

Here is sample PDF that i generated for testing.

[image]

Comment: Hi please look the question and provide the solution. how to load the external website with in the vf page and show as the pdf?

Comment: For including page just use Iframe and for generating PDF use the solution provided above.

Comment: Ok I will use the IFrame but how to make the pdf, I dont see the code in your answer. but that is paid verson so please help easiest way.

Comment: This is the easiest way i know my friend. Call Rest API and get the PDF! I do not have code ready but you should be able to figure that out.

Comment: Call Rest API and get the PDF! is too may stuff so can you guide anyother way?

Comment: @Lemon don't expect someone to write a whole solution for you. We are here to help when you're stuck with a specific problem and not do your job for you. If you do not know REST API and how to use 3rd party software, please read some documentation, get some training or contact the 3rd party for support.