# How to view the website in vf page as pdf

Tags: rerender

I have used the following code but the page shows as teh blank. but if we remove the render as pdf. the page shows the webpage.

**Code:**

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
  <apex:iframe height="300" width="180" src="https:www.google.com"  scrolling="true"  /> 
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cant render as PDFs the webpage. so just render as content and load into the outputpannel with the css style.

Answer (score 2):

You *had* a slight error on your apex page declaration (you originally had `render` prior to editing your question), it should actually be:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
```

Having said that, `<apex:iframe/>` is on the unsafe list when rendering as a PDF, so the content of the iFrame will not be displayed when displayed as PDF - hence the blank page.

Check [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_additional_render_pdf.htm) for best practices for rendering as PDF.

**EDIT:** Since you've edited your original question again to show the real page you're using (rather than google.com), why don't you modify `QOTD__QuoteMiniViewer` to render as PDF, say if you pass in a parameter? For example:

```
<apex:page renderAs="{!if($CurrentPage.parameters.p == null, null, 'pdf')}">
<!--page content-->
</apex:page>
```

Or, you could use `<apex:include/>`

Comment: You've edited your question now to show `renderAs`, it did show `render`. However, as I've stated `<apex:iframe/>` is on the unsafe list.

Comment: Yes. I have edited due to the spelling mistake. Can you help for the show the website as pdf?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do that because of the `<img>`'s in the page you're trying to display which is not supported when rendering as PDF.

Comment: @phil i dont want to render the content. i want to render the what exact shows in the vf page. can you help?

Comment: @Lemon, can you clarify the difference for you between render the page content vs. rendering the vf page exactly? The renderAs attribute will display the vf page's rendered content as PDF (https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_renderas_pdf.htm).

Comment: I would like to exact view webstie view as the pdf. not the content render. just load the yahoo.com and render as pdf. the pdf view should show as the yahoo.com got it?