# Attempt to de-reference a null object in dynamic calculate

Tags: pageblocktable, wrapper-class

I have used the following code and i am getting the error when lost focus from the second input filed. Kindly correct me in which line am using the code.

**Vf Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObject__c" extensions="mainClass" standardStylesheets="true" sidebar="false"> 
    <apex:actionFunction name="calmethod" action="{!calculate}" reRender="pgBlok3"/> 

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!getfunction}" var="sample">
     <apex:column ><apex:inputText value="{!sample.field1}"></apex:inputText></apex:column>
     <apex:column ><apex:inputText value="{!sample.field2}" onkeyup="calmethod()"></apex:inputText> </apex:column>                                      
    <apex:column > <apex:outputText >{!sample.grant}</apex:outputText></apex:column>
```

**APex Code:**

```
Public Class mainClass{

public class wrapper{
 public Decimal field1{get; set;}
 public Decimal field2{get; set;}
 public Decimal grant{get; set;}
}

 List<wrapper> listwrapper = new List<wrapper>();

public List<wrapper> getfunction(){
 wrapper obj= new wrapper();
 obj.grant=obj.field1+obj.field2;
 listwrapper.add(obj)

 return listwrapper;

}

  public void calculate(){
   wrapper newobj = new wrapper();
   newobj .grant=  newobj .fiel1+newobj .fiel2;
   }

}
```

Comment: Looks like a typo in your apex `calculate()` function.. fiel1 and fiel2 when should be **field1** and **field2**? Also, could you share how your `<apex:page>` tag is defined, particularly if any `standardController`, `controller`, or `extensions` attributes are used?

Answer (score 2):

I think I see what you're trying to do: take two numbers as input then compute the sum and display in third field. However, my answer below does not address the logic concerns of that but rather how to fix the null reference error you're asking about.

I see a couple typos in your code, which may just be from retyping the code into your question, but these are my recommendations:

1. In your `calculate()` apex function, the code is missing the letter **d**

   > `newobj .grant=  newobj .field1+newobj .field2;`
2. Also, your pageBlockTable `value` attribute does not need the `get` prefixbecause visualforce follows a getter/setter naming convention and assumes your apex class will provide a getXXX method where XXX is the name your visualforce references. In this case XXX is the word `function`. (As a programming tip, I recommend using more specific variable and function names to help self-describe their purpose).

   > `<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!function}" var="sample">`
3. The Null Pointer Exception is occuring in your apex class at line 13 because it attempts to sum field1 and field2 which are initially null (lines 4 and 5). You would need them initialized to non-null value, such as `0`

   > `obj.grant=obj.field1+obj.field2;`

With those changes made, your apex class would look like this:

```
public class mainClass{

    public class wrapper {
        public Decimal field1 {get; set;}
        public Decimal field2 {get; set;}
        public Decimal grant {get; set;}
        // define constructor to initialize values
        public wrapper() {
          this.field1 = 0;
          this.field2 = 0;
        }
    }

    List<wrapper> listwrapper = new List<wrapper>();

    public List<wrapper> getfunction(){
        wrapper obj= new wrapper();
        // if field1 or field2 are null then error will occur on next line
        obj.grant=obj.field1+obj.field2;
        listwrapper.add(obj);

        return listwrapper;

    }

    public void calculate(){
        wrapper newobj = new wrapper();
        newobj .grant=  newobj .field1+newobj .field2;
    }

}
```

and your visualforce page something like this:

```
<apex:page controller="mainClass">

    <apex:form>

        <apex:pageBlock id="pgBlok3">

            <apex:actionFunction name="calmethod" action="{!calculate}" reRender="pgBlok3"/> 

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!function}" var="sample">
                <apex:column ><apex:inputText value="{!sample.field1}"></apex:inputText></apex:column>
                <apex:column ><apex:inputText value="{!sample.field2}" onkeyup="calmethod()"></apex:inputText> </apex:column>                                      
                <apex:column > <apex:outputText >{!sample.grant}</apex:outputText></apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Nice answer, you are assign the value  like obj.field1 = 1;      obj.field2 = 2; but i would like to calculate dynamically. if we user type in the input field. it should calculate the value and display in grant input field.

Comment: Those were just example initializations. The field1 and field2 fields must not be null by the time you try and add them together to compute the `grant` value. You need to either initialize them to 0 or have an `IF` statement to conditionally try to sum the two fields if both are not null.

Comment: that was i am confusion in where we have to initialize to 0. if we initialize within the getfunciton(), all the time the value is 0. how to over come

Comment: You could add a constructor to the `wrapper` class; I'll update the sample code above to be more clear. You may want to check out some great training materials on apex and visualforce development at http://th3silverlining.com/2014/06/06/a-beginners-guide-to-object-oriented-programming-with-apex/ and http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_vf/

Comment: Really thanks for that and dont mistaken me for the question. Looking forward to see your update.

Comment: Thanks. can you answer for this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48226/how-to-view-the-website-in-vf-page-as-pdf?

Comment: If this answer solves your de-reference a null object question, please mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: NO. I have tried. but if I lost focus from the field2, the added value not display in the grant field. the reason is calculate() have the new instance. so how to display the added value in the grant field. when lost focus. it should be happen dynamically.

Comment: Kindly help to resolve the answer please read the above comment and help.